# Correction spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arccatalog

Please assist me on how to use ArcCatalog to confirm the spatial reference is correct and adjust if necessary.

Comment: Are you asking how to find what your data's projection currently is, or how to evaluate whether it has been set correctly (e.g. whether a projection was incorrectly applied)?

Comment: thank you for your respond, am asking how to correct the spatial using ArcCatalog. Thank you again

Comment: you mention arcCatalog but your tag is QGIS, which are you using ? Also, do you know the correct CRS ?

Comment: sorry, am using ArcCatalog

Answer (score 2):

First [open up ArcToolbox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003q0000001m000000.htm). Then there are two possible tools you can use (both in the Data Management / Projections and Transformations toolbox), depending on the specific situation:

- To define the projection, use the **[Define Projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000)** tool. Do this when:

  - no projection is currently assigned, or
  - the current projection is incorrect (e.g., data should be in NAD83 but it was incorrectly set to NAD27)
- To transform to a new projection, use the **[Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000)** tool.

  - Use when the projection is correct, but you want to *transform* the data to a new projection.

Answer (score 0):

To check the spatial reference, right-click the feature class/shapefile/raster and select properties, then the source tab. You should see both a projected and geographic coordinate system.

If you don't, or its wrong, follow Erica's answer.